# Create a new column with unique values from another in python Pandas - without grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, transform

I already posted a question, but I presented it badly.
Here my problem:

I have a dataframe like that:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | DESIRED COLUMN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SF | 123 | 01/02 | UP | UP, WA |
| BF | 543 | 30/12 | DO | DO, AF |
| QW | 241 | 30/12 | AF | DO, AF |
| SF | 123 | 01/02 | WA | UP, WA |
| QW | 789 | 20/11 | D | D |
| SF | 678 | 31/12 | OT | OT |

I wish to obtain the **DESIRED COLUMN**. The logic is the following:

- Have a condition that distinguishes the cases when Col1 is equal to SF or not
- In case Col1 is **NOT** equal to SF then I would *groupby* for Col3 and I would aggregate items of Col4
- In case Col1 is equal to SF then I would *groupby* for Col2 and Col3 and I would aggregate items of Col4

Where is my problem? I don't know if I overthought but using **groupby** pandas reduces the rows of the dataframe. My objective is simply to add a column, like I showed above.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Provide an output sample. Your condition did not state how you wanted to aggregate it.

Comment: @RaymondToh the output sample is the last column "DESIRED COLUMN"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df.Col1.eq('SF')

s1 = df.groupby(['Col2','Col3'])['Col4'].transform(', '.join)
s2 = df.groupby(['Col3'])['Col4'].transform(', '.join)
df['DESIRED COLUMN'] = np.where(m, s1, s2)
print (df)
  Col1  Col2   Col3 Col4 DESIRED COLUMN
0   SF   123  01/02   UP         UP, WA
1   BF   543  30/12   DO         DO, AF
2   QW   241  30/12   AF         DO, AF
3   SF   123  01/02   WA         UP, WA
4   QW   789  20/11    D              D
5   SF   678  31/12   OT             OT
```

Possible solution if `NaN`s in `Col2, Col3`:

```
m = df.Col1.eq('SF')

df1 = df.fillna({'Col2':'nan', 'Col3':'nan'})
s1 = df1.groupby(['Col2','Col3'])['Col4'].transform(', '.join)
s2 = df1.groupby(['Col3'])['Col4'].transform(', '.join)
df['DESIRED COLUMN'] = np.where(m, s1, s2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I got two errors:
s1:  ' Length mismatch: Expected axis has 84106 elements, new values have 133243 elements //

s2: Series' object has no attribute '_name'

Comment: @Frisk19 - What is your pandas version?

Comment: 1.1.5 -but i'm working with Spyder on a remote desktop of my company

Comment: @Frisk19 - Answer wa edited, `df1 = df.fillna({'Col2':'nan', 'Col3':'nan'})` and `s1 = df1.groupby(['Col2','Col3'])['Col4'].transform(', '.join)`, `s2 = df1.groupby(['Col3'])['Col4'].transform(', '.join)` Can you check?

Comment: Here we are!!! It seems everything ok!! God, finally. I want to add that, since I needed unique values on DESIRED COLUMN, inside the transform I wrote: "lambda x:', '.join(x.unique())" . Anyway many thanks to @jezrael for his help and responsiveness!! You saved my day:)